# CSS for multiple attributes?

Tags: html, css

I'm trying to consolidate the following:

```
input[type="text"] {
    width: 300px;
}
input[type="password"] {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Into something like this:

```
input[type="text"][type="password"] {
    width: 300px;
}
```

I tried this, `type="text", "password"`, and a few other things.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use many selectors as you want with `commas`,

```
input[type="text"],input[type="password"] {
    width: 300px;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Or simply

```
input { width: 300px; }
```

Then apply any other styles via type selectors

```
input[type="text"] { background: #ffd; }
input[type="password"] { background: #fff; }
```